# Get list of installed applications from Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I once saw a guy run a command and got a list of all installed applications on his computer. How do I do this?

I would like a list of my currently installed applications. I believe he used [WSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) somehow.

Comment: Related: [Is there a utility that will give me a list of all programs installed dumped to a text file for Windows?](http://superuser.com/q/202540/354511)  (not restricted to command line solutions).

Answer (score 53):

If you use [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista) or Windows 7 and you didn't want install additional software, you can:

1. Open a command-line window (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, CMD.EXE)
2. Type `wmic` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Type `product get name` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: +1 There's not much about your machine that WMI can't tell you these days.

Comment: Didn't know about this +1

Comment: Classy and useful

Comment: [here](http://blogs.sepago.de/helge/2010/01/14/how-to-list-all-installed-applications-from-the-command-line/) it says that Win32_Product will not give all the information about the installed softwares. That means, it will not list all the softwares. The reason for this is, win32_product queries the MSI database to get the list. But there will be many softwares which will not have a entry in it as they got installed from exe's. In this case querying the uninstall registry key gives information about these softwares.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Does it say that? (Is it the wrong link?) How would one query the uninstall registry in similar fashion? (or perhaps by using `wmic` itself?)

Comment: Also works with Windows 10

Comment: +1 On Windows Server 2012R2,`>wmic product get name, version > programs.txt` doens't get _everything_ listed in Add/Remove Programs, but gets most items, better than listing it all yourself, that's for sure.

Comment: Is it just me, or this runs very slow?

Comment: @MicTech: what about the size parameter? I'm getting `Description = invalid query`, and using this command: `wmic:root\cli>/output:C:\ProgramList.txt product get name, version, InstalledDate, size`. The problem is with **size** parameter

Comment: I can confirm what others mentioned in earlier comments: **this solution does not list all the applications**. Using Windows 10 22H2.

Comment: As per [Microsoft documentation on wmic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic), it is deprecated since Windows 10 21H1.

Answer (score 31):

[PsInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550.aspx) from Microsoft/Sysinternals can list all the installed software  if you use the **-s** flag when you run it.  You can also use **-c** to output it as a csv file to use in Excel for example.

```
C:\> psinfo -s > software.txt
C:\> psinfo -s -c > software.csv
```

Comment: also works unter Win XP in contrast to WMI solution

Comment: Does not show all installed software on `Windows 2012 R2 x64`. I'm using `PsInfo ver. 1.77`

Comment: This method produced 933 items on my laptop and the WMI method produced only 598. It seemed to produce a larger list...

Comment: @djhowell: I am trying to execute the command in Windows 7 but I get an error, " `psinfo is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` ". And this happens even in elevated rights cmd window.

Comment: _PsInfo_ is part of _Sysinternals Suite_ which you can install with `winget install -e --id 9P7KNL5RWT25`

Answer (score 18):

A PowerShell script to list them:

```ps
$loc = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

$names = $loc |foreach-object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath}

foreach ($name in $names)
{
    Write-Host $name.Displayname
}
```

Not exactly command line, but for this purpose I personally use [CCleaner's](http://ccleaner.com) uninstall tool, and you can export the list of installed software to a text file:

[image]

Comment: Rather ironic that the Windows Powershell etc tools take ages to run (>5 mins) but CCleaner is instant.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly command line either, but trusty old **[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/)** will do the job as well. Highlight *Applications*, right click → *Export To* → *CSV, HTML, TXT or XML*:

[image]

*SIW is freeware and portable, and installation isn't required.*

Comment: I have always know SIW to require a license, where are you getting it as Freeware?

Answer (score 4):

To add to [MicTech's solution](https://superuser.com/questions/68611/get-list-of-installed-applications-from-windows-command-line/68615#68615) - use `wmic` and capture the list of installed software to a file:

Open a command-line window (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, CMD.EXE)

```
wmic /OUTPUT:my_software.txt product get name
```

Comment: As per [Microsoft documentation on wmic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic), it is deprecated since Windows 10 21H1.

Comment: Shucks.  Thanks.  I'll double-check my current version of Windows and what the replacement might be.

Answer (score 3):

The CCleaner solution above seems like a decent way to go about it, unless you're determined to use the command-line.  I've used CCleaner before, it's a good tool  But don't assume that everything is registered in the Add/Remove Programs applet (the same list).  There are plenty of apps that use xcopy-style installation, i.e. simply unzip this archive and run.  Those will not show up in the list.

Answer (score 2):

[Sysinternals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals) psinfo.exe provides the most complete information of all the suggestions given, and it can be run on any Windows PC from the command line directly from an elevated CMD prompt, without permanent downloading:

```
\\live.sysinternals.com\tools\psinfo.exe -s > %userprofile%\Desktop\_psinfo.txt
```

You will get a security prompt when you run this, and a EULA prompt the first time on a machine. A text file will be saved to the current desktop.

The EULA can be automatically accepted like this:

```
\\live.sysinternals.com\tools\psinfo.exe -s /accepteula > %userprofile%\Desktop\_psinfo.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't work as of 2022 on Windows 10, `The network path was not found.`.

Answer (score 2):

I use powershell here:

```
Get-Package | 
  Where-Object {$_.ProviderName -in @('Programs','msi','chocolatey')} |
    Select-Object * | 
      Out-GridView "Installed programs"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, Size, InstallDate | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

It worked for me. source - https://www.howtogeek.com/165293/how-to-get-a-list-of-software-installed-on-your-pc-with-a-single-command/

Comment: FWIW, this method did not list all of the packages that the WMIC command did.

Answer (score 0):

The encoded version in C# installed programs via Windows registry:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace SoftwareInventory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //!!!!! Must be launched with a domain administrator user!!!!!
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            StringBuilder sbOutFile = new StringBuilder();
            Console.WriteLine("DisplayName;IdentifyingNumber");
            sbOutFile.AppendLine("Machine;DisplayName;Version");

            // Retrieve machine name from the file :File_In/collectionMachines.txt
            //string[] lines = new string[] { "NameMachine" };
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"File_In/collectionMachines.txt");
            foreach (var machine in lines)
            {
                // Retrieve the list of installed programs for each extrapolated machine name
                var registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
                using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, machine).OpenSubKey(registry_key))
                {
                    foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                    {
                        using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
                            //Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("IdentifyingNumber"));
                            if (subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", machine, subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"), subkey.GetValue("Version")));
                                sbOutFile.AppendLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", machine, subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"), subkey.GetValue("Version")));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // CSV file creation
            var fileOutName = string.Format(@"File_Out\{0}_{1}.csv", "Software_Inventory", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mmssfff"));
            using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileOutName))
            {
                file.WriteLine(sbOutFile.ToString());
            }

            // Press Enter to continue 
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```