# Is there a utility that will give me a list of all programs installed dumped to a text file for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm on a machine that has a preposterous amount of software installed and I'd like to be able to generate some sort of quick report that will list all of the installed applications.

Is there a program that does this?

I am using Windows 7, however I imagine that if such a tool exists that it would exist for other versions of the Windows operating system as well.

Comment: Related: [Get list of installed applications from Windows command line](http://superuser.com/q/68611/354511).

Comment: Highly recommend [uninstallview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/uninstall_view.html). It is free and can export every installed program (x86, x64, system, Microsoft store apps) to html-table or txt. Before exporting you can set sorting and select any columns you would like to see in report (version, install date, path, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

[I would highly recommend Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html)

as it gives you an overview of the most important information you might want to have of your machine. Including hardware and software. Oh and it's free too!

[Here's an example you can find through Google](http://users.telenet.be/brettw/profiel.htm)

[image]

Note: Don't publish your Belarc profile on Google as it contains license keys and perhaps other 'useful' information!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like [System Information for Windows](http://www.gtopala.com/).  For home use, it's FREE.  For a technician, you can get a fairly cheap license that lets YOU run it on any computer you want.  And it's a single file (well, when registered, there's also a license file).  And it will export to HTML and the paid version can also do XML and CSV (and another format I've forgotten).

And if this is a network that you might have to get information on more than one machine, then you can try [SpiceWorks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) which is free even in a business environment (generally minimal/unobtrusive ads).

Comment: SIW is no longer free (going by its download page), and its only free-to-download version is bundled with adware (hence my downvote). Free versions seem to exist on third-party download sites, though.

Comment: How to use SpiceWorks on a local (personal) machine?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this without installing any software go to the command prompt with Administrator privilege:

1. Windows button
2. Type "`cmd`"
3. Ctrl-Shift-Enter on the Command Prompt (this gives you Admin privilege)
4. Run "`wmic`"
5. Type "`/output:C:\InstallList.txt product get name,version`"

A text file should exist in the c: root directory

Comment: Thanks. Works for many programs but misses things like Google Chrome that are installed in a rather non-standard manner.

Comment: This method gives you only programms that were installed with Windows Installer. Many programs will be missing such as: FireFox, Chrome, Opera, 7-Zip, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The [MyUninstaller](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/myuninst.html) freeware utility from NirSoft can save the list of installed applications in different formats (text, tab delimited, HTML and XML). It is tiny and doesn't need to be installed.

Comment: "Notice: MyUninstaller is very old tool and it's not updated anymore, you are welcomed to try the new [UninstallView tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/uninstall_view.html)"

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Piriform's "CCleaner" it allows you to export a list with a lot more information that some others.