# Way To Create A Reference List For All Installed Applications/Programs On My PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, package-management

Is there an **built-in** way or ways in Windows to show (alphabetically ideally) all the programs/applications that are installed on my Windows PC that can then be saved as a PDF or Word document for future reference, rather than carrying out a manual search for each and every program?

Please note: I am looking for inbuilt ways rather than using 3rd party software to achieve the objective.

Comment: @techie007 That question solely relies on the use of additional 3rd party software, and doesn't ask for inbuilt ways within Windows to achieve the same objective, as answered by Taylor Gibb.

Comment: One of the answers (http://superuser.com/a/293674/23133) gives a way using the inbuilt WMI features of Windows. Perhaps remove your request for a 3rd party utility and demand all answers be in-built if that's what you actually want.  Otherwise, it's a dupe IMO.

Comment: @techie007 Yes thats true :)

Comment: @techie007 ok I shall. Actually the reason I included 3rd party in the beginning was because I thought it might not be possible.

Comment: @techie007 Done, please kindly remove duplicate question.

Comment: Can't, that's why it takes 5 to close. :)

Comment: @techie007 Oh... So what happens then ?

Comment: @techie007 I guess it has been marked as a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cool problem to solve using PowerShell.

Firstly you need to open PowerShell. You can do this by pressing the Windows + R keyboard combination, typing powershell into the run box and pressing enter.

Now simply type the following into the PowerShell Window.

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name > C:\apps.txt`

For a CSV just use the following (note i used some aliases to shorten the command but it still does the same thing):

`gwmi -Class Win32_Product | select -Property Name | Export-CSV "C:\apps.csv"`

Comment: if you want to get really fancy you can even export it to a CSV file so that you can compare lists at a later point in time to see what you dont have installed.

Comment: Thanks for that, I agree if there is an inbuilt way then it should have first priority. Can a CSV file be opened with MS Excel or similar ?

Comment: @Simon indeed it can. Please mark this answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: I have never used CSV files before, so just needed clarification. I usually wait a couple of days before marking a correct answer (if you don't mind) :)

Comment: @Simon Sure, you can wait if you want. I updated the answer to include a command that exports your programs to a CSV. You can then simply open the file from Excel.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. (I think you mean updated the answer not question) in your comment above

Comment: @Simon yup, i did indeed :P

Comment: Welcome..... :)

Comment: I slightly altered my question to exclude the use of 3rd party software to prevent it from being a duplicate. If you would kindly edit the 1st sentence of your answer accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Funny...Isn't 3rd party software basically anything which didn't come bundled in the OS? Anyway, personally I'm a fan of WinAudit- PC Audit & Inventory Software http://winaudit.zymichost.com/index.html

Comment: Yes a 3rd party software is software that doesn't come bundled with an OS

Comment: The question has now changed to inbuilt ways only. Thanks for answering, if you would kindly delete though.

Comment: It's ironic that some are hesitant to run a 3rd party application to list all the 3rd party programs installed on a system...

Comment: Not hesitant to run a third party program, the question was changed to prevent it from being a possible duplicate.